# How do I get this if statement to finish executing before the rest of the code runs?

Tags: javascript

This is a simple version of what I'm trying to do in my application. I have an if statement which evaluates the result of a function call and then populates an array if the statement comes back as true. AFTER the if statement is completely finished, I want to run some more code such as the console.log as seen below.

I understand that the if's evaluation is taking too long to finish and javascript just continues to the console.log because of its asynchronicity. How do I make the code wait for the if statement to complete?

```
var tabs = [];

if (isTrue()) {
    tabs.push('some string');
}

console.log(tabs[1]);

function isTrue() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        return true;
    }, 500)
}
```

Comment: You would define isTrue as a function that takes a callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just wrap your code in a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and consume the returned values by calling [`then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) on it:

```js
var tabs = [];
isTrue().then(res => {
  if (res) {
    tabs.push('some string');
  }
  return tabs;
}).then(arr => {
  console.log(arr);
});



function isTrue() {
  //Just wrap your existing code in a Promise constructor
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      //Pass whatever value you want to consume later to resolve
      resolve(true);
    }, 500)
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could pass a callback to the `isTrue()` function, something like:

```
function isTrue(_callback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        // code here

        // Call the callback when done
        if (typeof(_callback) === 'function')
            _callback(tabs);
    });
}

function showTabs(tabs) {
    console.log(tabs[1]);
}

isTrue(showTabs);
```

Ought to work.

Answer (score 1):

Using modern javascript, you can achieve that using [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function):

```
const isTrue = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500, true));

// you can only use `await` inside an `async` function
async function main() {
  // better use `let` instead of `var` since `let` is block scoped,
  // see:
  // <https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let>

  let tabs = [];

  if (await isTrue()) {
    tabs.push('some string');
  }

  // array's index start by 0, not 1
  console.log(tabs[0]);
}

main();
```

(this code also use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) for `isTrue`.)

Answer (score 0):

`isTrue()` returns *undefined*. The `return true` inside of the `setTimeout` callback will return back to the timeout call, not to the `isTrue()` call. The code executes immeadiately and there is no asynchronity involved (except for that timer that does nothing).